On what properties of material does inelastic collision depends
I want to know on which properties of a material an inelastic collision depends; specifically, on which properties the loss of kinetic energy depends. Also, why does an inelastic collision or loss of kinetic energy depend on these material properties?

AFAIK, it is viscosity (internal friction) of the material. Kinetic energy must somehow be transformed into internal energy and that's what friction does.

Since energy loss involves deformation, the harder the material generally the more elastic the collision. Think billiard balls

but a rubber creates less sound and travel more distance as compared to an steel ball when drop to ground -
